# Where are the code segments stored in memory

Tags: memory-management, segment

I cannot find a clear answer for where the different segments (based on Wikipedia) are actually stored in memory (e.g. for pic32).

```
Data Segment (Data + BSS + Heap) : RAM? 
Stack                            : RAM?    
Code segment                     : flash?
```

Comment: Where every you tell it to store it. AFAIK, code can be in RAM or FLASH, and can be executed directly from either.

Comment: But if i have a flash table like this "static myTable_t MyTable[MAX_SIZE];"
and i change some values, will it be written directly to flash?

But often there are some special functions like "write_to_flash" - what is the point of those then?

Comment: I now read that i can set a variable in flash memory like this: "uint8 Gain_factor_Den_17[128] __attribute__((space(prog), section(".table_flash_control")));" But what happens when i change that variable, flash has some requirements (e.g. need to erase page before writing etc). Who will handle that?